# pysnmp setcmd "No Such Object currently exists at this OID"

Tags: pysnmp, oid

I need to set some OID parameters using Python.
I made this simple script using pysnmp library. It correctly reads OID's but when I try to set one just read I receive the message "No Such Object currently exists at this OID".
Can help me? Thank you in advance.

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
print "Get OID"
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('public'),
       UdpTransportTarget((hostIP, 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0')),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2.1')),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.1')))
)
for varBind in varBinds:
print varBind

print "Set OID"    
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    setCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
       UdpTransportTarget((hostIP, 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.1'),
                  OctetString('new value')))
)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print varBind
```

---

I used a MIB Browser (CommunityData='private' for setting) and I was able to set specific OID for that snmp v2 device (Selta ONU), providing credentials in specific OID's.

This was the sequence of setting:

1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.1.1.0 = "username"

1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.1.2.0 = "password"

1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.2.0=1 (session status = START)

after the session is started I set the parameter

1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.6.3.29.1.4.1 = "17a_RTX"

1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.2.0=3 (session status = COMMIT)

so the new value was stored.
After this successful experience I modified the Python script in this way:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
print "Get OID"
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('public'),
       UdpTransportTarget(('163.162.105.120', 161)),
       ContextData(),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0')),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0')),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.3.0')) # get session status
       )
)
for varBind in varBinds:
    print varBind

print "Set Credentials"
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    setCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('private', mpModel=1),
       UdpTransportTarget(('163.162.105.120', 161)),
       ContextData(), ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.1.1.0'),OctetString('username')),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.1.2.0'),OctetString('password')),
       ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.2.0'),Integer(1)) # open session
       )
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                    errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print varBind

print "Set OID"
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    setCmd(SnmpEngine(),
       CommunityData('private', mpModel=1),
       UdpTransportTarget(('163.162.105.120', 161)),
       ContextData(),  ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.6.3.29.1.4.1'),OctetString('17a_noRTX')))
)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)
elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                    errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print varBind
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
Get OID
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = SAMBHA
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = Cadeo(PC)
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.10060.1.6.10.4.3.0 = 0
Set Credentials
'noSuchName' at 1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.1.2.0
Set OID
'authorizationError' at 1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.6.3.29.1.4.1
```

The same OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.10.4.1.2.0 that was set in MIB Browser is not seen in the script.
Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issues with your code so far. I am pretty confident that's your SNMP agent not allowing you to modify the managed object you want to modify.

Does it work with Net-SNMP's snmpset?

```
snmpset -v1 -c public  1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.3.1 s 'new value'
```

BTW, often times SNMP agents are configured to use different SNMP community strings for read and write operations. Sometimes the default is **private** for writes.

Answer (score 0):

@Ilya, my tries with net-snmp.

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public 163.162.105.120 1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.6.3.29.1.11.1
```

SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.10060.1.6.6.3.29.1.11.1 = STRING: "VirtualNoiseProfile"

```
snmpset -v 2c -c public 163.162.105.120 1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.6.3.29.1.11.1 s "new string"
```

Error in packet.
Reason: noAccess

```
snmpset -v 2c -c private 163.162.105.120 1.3.6.1.4.1.10060.1.6.6.3.29.1.11.1 s "new string"
```

Error in packet.
Reason: authorizationError (access denied to that object)
Failed object: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.10060.1.6.6.3.29.1.11.1

The host doesn't allow set operation, nor public neither private, also if the python message is
misleading ("No Such Object currently exists at this OID").
I should learn how to set an authorization profile, I suppose. But I haven't found any examples.
Thank you.

Comment: PySNMP message isn't misleading, but a good indicator. If you changed your NET-SNMP command line to `-v 1` you should observe the same. That's because the error reason `noAccess` or `authorizationError` was only introduced in SNMP v2c. So when SNMP v1 operations hit such issues, the closest is `noSuchObject`.